# HTML/jQuery client and PHP backend for Twitter oAuth

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-oauth

I'm using this twitter oAuth library (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) and the following to implement it. This code (call it testing.php) directs the user to the twitter auth page and then back with auth tokens and returns some info about their account. Works great.

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once ('twitteroauth/autoload.php');
$consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$callback = "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (isset($_SESSION['oauth_token'])) {
    $oauth_token = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
    unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
    $connection = new Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $params = array("oauth_verifier" => $_GET['oauth_verifier'], 'oauth_token' => $_GET['oauth_token']);
    $access_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/access_token', $params);
    $connection = new Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
    print_r($content);
} else {
    $connection = new Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $temporary_credentials = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array("oauth_callback" => $callback));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $temporary_credentials['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $temporary_credentials['oauth_token_secret'];
    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authenticate', array('oauth_token' => $temporary_credentials['oauth_token']));
    header('Location: ' . $url);
}
```

However, I'd like to build my frontend using HTML and javascript/jQuery (index.html) and not PHP (index.php).

I've tried to adjust the callbacks in here and using AJAX to call this PHP, but I can't get anything returned to the HTML because of cross-scripting restrictions. How do you actually go from HTML => PHP => Twitter Auth page => PHP => HTML

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help http://140dev.com/download/javascript_ebook.pdf .
It contains rich examples as well.
However 'tmhOAuth' php library is used rather than twitteroauth.